# Unable to deploy Azure Function ZIP file through CLI command

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-cli, azure-private-link

I had developed azure function with private endpoint(disabled public access) `HTTP Trigger` using `.NET Core C#`.

Since inbound traffic for function , storage is cut off with internet access, I published my ZIP to a storage account(Newly created apart of storage that linked to function app and public enabled) via build(CI) pipeline and fetching the same ZIP file in release pipeline to deploy.

ZIP_URL : I can see ZIP URL with SAS token attached in logs.

I tried below commands for ZIP deployment in `Azure CLI Task` but none are helping me. So i tried to run locally in my machine and getting different issues as shown below respectively.

**Command 1:**

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --name demo-funcapp-test --resource-group osh-poc-rg --src $ZIP_URL
```

[image]

**Command 2:**

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g osh-poc-rg -n demo-funcapp-test --src $ZIP_URL
```

[image]

**Command 3:**

```
az webapp deploy --name demo-funcapp-test --resource-group osh-poc-rg --type zip --src-url $ZIP_URL --async false
```

[image]

**Command 4:**

```
az rest --method PUT --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/55555c7b-1f7a-43a1-a90f-dee45a2f6262/resourceGroups/osh-poc-rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/demo-funcapp-test/extensions/onedeploy?api-version=2022-03-01 --body "{'properties': {'type': 'zip','packageUri': '${ZIP_URL}' }}"
```

[image]

**Updated:** After creating VM with same VNET as function app and modifying agent to Self host, I successfully abled to deploy but functions are not showing in Azure Portal.
[image]

Comment: az webapp deployment source config-zip --name demo-funcapp-test --resource-group osh-poc-rg --src $ZIP_URL > Here ZIP URL Seems to be of c:\\Users. You can add the zip file as a blob inside a storage container and then create SAS token URL with the zipped blob and add it in this ZIP_URL

Comment: As your function is behind a private endpoint, You can add one VM in the same VNet as your private function app and then add that VM as a self hosted agent in your azure devops, Then run this az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g siliconrg54 -n
siliconfunc65 --src "Syste.DefaultWorkingDirectory/funcapp.zip" inside your Devops cli task given your zipped folder is in azure repos

Comment: If your function app and storage is publicly enabled, Refer my SO thread answer here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76296061/very-slow-to-deploy-after-updating-website-run-from-package/76303791#76303791

Comment: @SiddheshDesai I tried alternative approach you mentioned such as add VM and use it as self hosted agent. I did the same and deployed function with azure cli task ```az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g siliconrg54 -n siliconfunc65 --src "Syste.DefaultWorkingDirectory/funcapp.zip"``` but the function is not showing up in Azure portal . I updated my question with snapshots.:(

Comment: If you are using Azure python Functions v2 make sure to have this setting -AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags
EnableWorkerIndexing > Reference my So answer -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76559759/azure-functions-python-programming-model-v2-1-found-0-loaded/76562032#76562032

Comment: If you are using Azure Python Functions v1 - Refer my SO answer here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76276661/unable-to-explain-why-my-python-based-azure-function-is-not-appearing-when-using/76277867#76277867

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood the root cause of issue.

The problem lies in zip file that build through CI pipeline. The zip file folder structure is incorrect.

**ZIP file and folder structure before Issue fix:** The azure function app code files resides inside `build` folder that downloaded build.zip artifact from build pipeline as show in below screenshot.

Azure CLI task in unable to parse and deploy ZIP file, I see below log information in release logs file.

```
Bad Request({"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"System.ArgumentException: Invalid '/home/azureadminuser/myagent/_work/r1/a/_POCPrivateEndpoints-CI/drop/build.zip' packageUri in the JSON request\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Deployment.PushDeploymentController.<PushDeployAsync>d__16.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services\\Deployment\\PushDeploymentController.cs:line 474"}})
```

[image]

**Changes done to CI pipeline:**

using `Pipeline Copy file task`, I to make sure there is no `build` folder inside it.

[image]

Next In archive files Task i modified `rootFolderOrFile` to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/build`

And it worked like a champ :)